# What Counts as Statistically Significant?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Problem:**

In clinical trails of Nasonex, $3774$ adult and adolescent allergy patients
were randomly divided into two groups.

The patients in **Group** $1$ (*experimental group*) received $200$ mcg of Nasonex, while the patients in **Group** $2$ (*control
group*) received a placebo.

- Of the $2013$ patients in the experimental
  group, $547$ reported headaches as a side effect.
- Of the $1671$ patients
  in the control group, $368$ reported headaches as side effect.

> Is there
>   sufficient evidence to support the claim that users of Nasonex experience
>   headaches?

**Partial Solution**

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be the ratio of patients in the two control groups that
experience headaches.
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_1 &=& \frac{547}{2013} = 0.27173 \\
p_2 &=& \frac{368}{3774-2013} = 0.2089722 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

> Is this statistically significant? How do I tell?

Comment: Does the number $368$ or anything that implies $368$ appear anywhere in your question before where you wrote "Answer:"?  Where did $368$ come from? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Of the 3774 - 2013 = 1761 (I assume) patients in the control group (receiving a placebo), how many had headaches? Is that the missing count 368 noted by @Michael Hardy? It seems to me that info is crucial to testing whether the groups differ as to headaches. Please look at the original problem and proofread your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to test whether there is a statistical
significance between two binomial proportions. Because you seem
to have left out some key information in your posted version of 
the problem (as commented by @MichaelHardy), I will use my own numbers. You can use the same
procedures I show below with the correct numbers, whatever they are.
Although I give some references, I suppose that one or both of the methods illustrated will be
explained in your text or class notes.

Control group (placebo): 1500 subjects, of whom 500 report headaches.

Treatment group (Nasonex): 2000 subjects, of whom 550 report headaches.

**Equality of two binomial proportions.** The hypothesis to be tested is $H_0: \pi_C = \pi_T$ against
the alternative $H_A: \pi_C \ne \pi_T,$ where $\pi_C$ and $\pi_T$
denote the population proportions of allergy patients with headaches in the control and treatment groups, respectively.

The estimate of $\pi_C$ is $\hat \pi_C = \#(\text{Ctrl headaches})/n_C = 500/1500 = 0.333$.
Similarly $\hat \pi_T = 550/2000 = 0.275.$

A commonly used test statistic in this instance (see, for example,
Ott & Longnecker, 7e, pg 494 or various Internet pages [including Penn State](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat500/node/55)) is as follows:

$Z = N/D,$ where $N ={\hat \pi_C - \hat \pi_T}$ and 
$D = \sqrt{(\hat \pi_C (1 - \hat \pi_C) /n_C + 
(\hat \pi_T(1 - \hat \pi_T) /n_T}.$
Thus, $$Z = \frac{0.333 - 0.275}{\sqrt{0.000148+.0000997}}
= \frac{.058}{0.01574} = 3.7.$$

Because $|Z| > 1.96,$ we reject $H_0$.

Here is Minitab output for this test:

```
 MTB > PTwo 1500 500 2000 550.

 Test and CI for Two Proportions 

 Sample    X     N  Sample p
 1       500  1500  0.333333
 2       550  2000  0.275000

 Difference = p (1) - p (2)
 Estimate for difference:  0.0583333
 95% CI for difference:  (0.0274780, 0.0891886)
 Test for difference = 0 (vs not = 0):  
      Z = 3.71  P-Value = 0.000
```

**Homogeneity of proportions in a $2 \times 2$ contingency table.** An equivalent method is to use a chi-squared test of
homogeniety on the number of subjects with headaches
in each group and the number of subjects in each group. (See various Internet pages, [including Vasser.)](http://vassarstats.net/tab2x2.html)

In R statistical software, this test can be done as follows:

```
 headaches = c(500,550)
 subjects = c(1500,2000)
 prop.test(headaches, subjects, correct=F)

 > prop.test(headaches, subjects, correct=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

 data:  headaches out of subjects 
 X-squared = 13.8889, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001939
 alternative hypothesis: two.sided 
 95 percent confidence interval:
  0.02747802 0.08918865 
 sample estimates:
    prop 1    prop 2 
 0.3333333 0.2750000
```

Because the P-value is far below 5%, we strongly reject the null hypothesis that the proportions are equal. Notice that the chi-squared statistic here has $\sqrt{13.8898} \approx  3.7,$ which was the $Z$
statistic in the test above.

**Addendum.** Now that the question has been edited to show
more information, I include the corresponding Minitab output:

```
 MTB > PTwo 2013 547 1671 368

 Test and CI for Two Proportions 

 Sample    X     N  Sample p
 1       547  2013  0.271734
 2       368  1671  0.220227

 Difference = p (1) - p (2)
 Estimate for difference:  0.0515063
 95% CI for difference:  (0.0237137, 0.0792990)
 Test for difference = 0 (vs not = 0):  
      Z = 3.63  P-Value = 0.000
```

Notice that the two point estimates agree with those in the
question. Again here, a very small P-value indicates that the two groups are significantly different.

Comment: If something remains unclear about the procedures, please let us know. Perhaps someone can clarify.

Comment: It should be added that group sizes (control vs treatment) strongly suggest that patients were not "randomly divided into two groups" which would make me question the rest of experimental procedure/validity of reporting.

Comment: Another potential difficulty: If you have both a very stuffy nose and a slight headache, suppose the drug cures the stuffy nose. Then you might start to notice the headache and report it as a side effect of the drug.