# Test to compare two proportions when samples are of very different sizes

Tags: statistics

I found a paper where two groups were being tested as applicants for jobs, where only one "sort" of trait was changed in the applicants. I am renaming things to avoid off topic responses. The trait was put into two categories, Group A, and Group B.

Group A received a positive response of 10.7% with 984 data points.

Group B received a positive response of 6.2% with 1974 data points.

Total data points: 2958
Group A percentage of total data points: 33.2657
Group B percentage of total data points: 66.7343

I concluded that the difference in the amount of data points was significant enough to alter the outcome of the test, thus rendering the results of the test inconclusive/invalid. Is my line of reasoning accurate/sound? If not, what things did I miss, and how can I better analyze data sets like this in the future?

(if more information is required, I am more than happy to provide any information I have on hand)

Comment: I think the experts at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be better placed to answer this question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'm gonna leave this here in case someone is able to answer, as StackExchange permits 1 question per 40 minutes across all sites.

Comment: @Rahul. This question is well-suited to the (statistics) tag on our site.

Comment: IMHO, this question should not be put on hold. It asks a legitimate and thoughtful question about statistics within the scope of our (statistics) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Imbalance.** I will begin by addressing your misgivings about grossly
different sample sizes.

A 'balanced' experiment in which the numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ of subjects
in the two groups are equal is most efficient. "A chain is only a strong as it's
weakest link." For you, group A with $n_1 = 984$ subjects is the weak link, compared
with group B with $n_2 = 1974.$ So, *very* roughly speaking, you would
have about as much 'power' to distinguish between groups if $n_2 \approx 984.$
But a somewhat suboptimal design hardly makes the data worthless.

**Test for difference of two proportions.** This situation requires a standard test for comparing two proportions. You want to
test $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against $H_a: p_1 \ne p_2,$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$
are the proportions of positive responses in the *populations*
represented by groups A and B, respectively. You can find versions of this
test based on normal approximations to the binomial distributions in most
elementary texts. With sample sizes as large as yours, the normal
approximation should work fine.

Versions of the test vary slightly from one textbook
to another. I will show you results from Minitab 17 software for one of the versions
and also for Fisher's Exact Test.
You have about $X_1 = 0.107(984) = 105$ positive results in Group A and 
$X_2 = 0.062(1974) = 122$ positive results in Group B. (These numbers
are necessary input to the Minitab procedure; because of rounded proportions
I cannot recover these counts exactly, but close enough for a valid test.)

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X     N  Sample p
1       108   984  0.109756
2       122  1974  0.061803

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0479527
95% CI for difference:  (0.0257200, 0.0701853)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 4.23  P-Value = 0.000

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.000
```

The very small P-values (below 0.0005) indicate that you can reject $H_0$
at any reasonable significance level. That is, it would be extremely
unlikely to get sample proportions as far apart as observed here if the populations
A and B had equal proportions of positive results.

[Also notice the confidence interval given in the output. It does not contain $0.$
This is an indication that the two groups are dissimilar as to proportion of
positive results.]

So the bottom line is that, although the design is technically somewhat inefficient, you have plenty of information in these data to reach a
solid statistical conclusion.

I hope you can find a version of this test comparing two proportions in
your textbook. The result is sufficiently strong that it shouldn't
make any difference which version you use.

Comment: If not in a textbook at hand, Z is computed using (9.1) in [_these notes_](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wardrop/courses/371chapter9b.pdf). Also possibly helpful [_this Q & A_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580297/what-counts-as-statistically-significant/1580420#1580420).